# Extracting attributes from array of objects based on other attributes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have array of objects , and would like to fetch some attributes based on another one

assume

```
var lngs = [{id : 3 , label : 'a'} , {id : 2 , label : 'b' , {id : 4 , label : 'c'}];
```

now I need to get array of labels based on ids

for example

```
getAttrs([4,3]);

function getAttrs(ids , arr)
{
   // as long as ids = [4,3] , it should return
   ["c","a"]
}
```

I tried this algorithm , but it did not work as expected

```
 langsFromIds(ids)
 {
   var rslt = [];
   var lngs = this.state.langs;
   for (var i = 0 ; i < lngs.length ; i++)
   {
     if (lngs[i].id == ids[i])
     {
       rslt.push(lngs[i].label);
     }
   }

   return rslt;
 }
```

because it runs in this way (for example)

> first iteration (i==0) => lngs[i].id == 3 && ids[i] == 4 (will not match)
>
> second iteration (i==1) => lngs[i].id == 2 && ids[i] == 3 (will not match)
>
> and so on ..

so it will return empty array

Comment: You need to loop inside again and not match index to index.

Comment: Your `lngs` object is syntactically invalid. I have posted my answer assuming `var lngs = [{id : 3 , label : 'a'} , {id : 2 , label : 'b'} , {id : 4 , label : 'c'}];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter down to the corrects ids, then extract the desired labels:

```js
var lngs = [{id : 3 , label : 'a'} , {id : 2 , label : 'b'} , {id : 4 , label : 'c'}];

function langsFromIds(ids, langs)
{
  return langs.filter(lng => ids.indexOf(lng.id) > -1).map(lng => lng.label);
}

console.log(langsFromIds([4, 3], lngs));
```

Comment: It works well I think , thanks
I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get a list of individual `lng` objects...

```js
var lngs = [{id:3,label:'a'},{id:2,label:'b'},{id:4,label:'c'}];

function lngsFromIds(ids) {
  return lngs.filter(x => ids.find(y => y == x.id));
}
console.log(lngsFromIds([3,4]));
```

And then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the `label` as well...

```js
var lngs = [{id:3,label:'a'},{id:2,label:'b'},{id:4,label:'c'}];

function labelsFromIds(ids) {
  return lngs.filter(x => ids.find(y => y == x.id)).map(z => z.label);
}
console.log(labelsFromIds([3,4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my proposition :

```
var lngs = [{id : 3 , label : 'a'} , {id : 2 , label : 'b' }, {id : 4 , label : 'c'}];

var npq = getAttrs([4,3]);
console.log(npq);

function getAttrs(ids)
{
   var rslt = [];
   //var lngs = this.state.langs;
    for (var k = 0; k < ids.length; k++)
    {
        for (var i = 0 ; i < lngs.length ; i++)
        {
          if (lngs[i].id == ids[k])
          {
             rslt.push(lngs[i].label);
          }
        }
    }
   return rslt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- To answer your question, you are matching index to index and hence you won't get the desired result as the `id` could be found anywhere in `ids`.
- A quick solution is to iterate inside again on `ids` and if a match is found, you add them in the result.

```js
var lngs = [{id:3,label:'a'},{id:2,label:'b'},{id:4,label:'c'}];

function langsFromIds(ids)
 {
   var rslt = [];
   for (var i = 0 ; i < lngs.length ; i++)
   {
     for(var j=0; j < ids.length;j++)
     {
       if (lngs[i].id == ids[j])
      {
         rslt.push(lngs[i].label);
      }  
     }
   }

   return rslt;
 }

console.log(langsFromIds([3,4]));
```

- Although the above solution works, it isn't scalable, meaning above solution would take a lot of time to return a result if size of `lngs` goes huge along with `ids`. In other words, time complexity is `O(n * m)` where `n` is the size of `lngs` and `m` is the size of `ids`.
- So, **`if`** you are aiming for an efficient approach, you could make a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `ids` and check for a match in `lngs`.

```js
var lngs = [{id:3,label:'a'},{id:2,label:'b'},{id:4,label:'c'}];

function lngsFromIds(ids) {
  var set = new Set(ids);
  return lngs.filter(x => set.has(x.id)).map(x => x.label);
}
console.log(lngsFromIds([3,4]));
```

- Above approach can decide whether the current object's `id` is present in `ids` or not in on an average O(1) time, hence making the function faster. Time complexity would be `O(n + m)` time with an additional space trade off of `O(m)` where `n` and `m` are same as mentioned before.